# Rails: How to convert a query result hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am currently struggling with something which should be pretty straightforward in Rails.

I would like to issue one ActiveRecord query and fetch model objects from the database and subsequently store those in a hash for later lookup.

I have done some research but haven't found the optimal way to accomplish this, so would appreciate some help. My intention is to reduce the number of sql queries using lookup hashes in loop structures.

In the pseudo code below,  I am fetching status codes from an sms gateway and compare those with an ActiveRecord table will all status-code descriptions.

```
#Status_codes in array format
status_codes = StatusCode.all

status_codes_hash = status_codes.to_array????

#Fetch delivery-status from sms gateway
response = HTTParty.get(myUrl)

response.each do |status|
if status_codes_hash[status.code]
    #Do stuff
end
end
```

Comment: how many status codes you have ? i will suggest keep the status codes as class level variables ?

Answer (score 4):

Use this snippet to get your hash of statuses with their codes as keys:

```
status_codes.group_by(&:code)
```

The snippet is a shortcut for `status_codes.group_by{|status| status.code}`

It would also be better and more universal to check the key like this:

```
if status_codes_hash.has_key?(status.code)
    # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You convert a model instance to hash via the [attributes method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes):

```
StatusCode.all.map(&:attributes)
#=> [{ id: 1, code: 404, ...}, { id: 2, code: 405, ...}, ...]
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a Hash with an array of key value pairs like this:

```
Hash[/an array of key values goes here/]
```

So all you have to do is convert your StatusCodes to key value pairs and use it as input for Hash[]

like this

```
Hash[status_codes.map{|sc|[sc.code, sc]}]
```

Should do the trick

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D

Answer (score 0):

The `inject` method is a convenient way to do what you're looking for, I think.

```
status_codes_hash = status_codes.inject({}) do |hash, obj|
  hash[obj.code] = obj
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version for ActiveRecord:

```
Currency.all.map { [_1.iso_code, _1] }.to_h
```

returns:

```
=> { 'USD' => #<Currency id: 1, territory: "United States", name: "United States dollar", symbol: "$", iso_code: "USD", ...
```